# Google Colab crash/unknown error when running keras model.predict()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, crash-reports, predict, google-colaboratory

I am training a model in keras. model.fit() is working and the model trained but when i run model.predict, google colab session crashes.
Here is the log:

`Nov 15, 2020, 3:04:50 AM  WARNING WARNING:root:kernel b48211a4-a3e6-44f4-8082-89f69da39d21 restarted`
`Nov 15, 2020, 3:04:50 AM  INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports`
`Nov 15, 2020, 3:04:47 AM  WARNING 2020-11-15 02:04:47.189399: F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:533] Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(handle_.get(), elem_type, nd, dims.data(), strides.data()) == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (9 vs. 0)batch_descriptor: {count: 20 feature_map_count: 512 spatial: 399 598 value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX}`
`Nov 15, 2020, 3:04:47 AM  WARNING 2020-11-15 02:04:47.189282: W tensorflow/core/kernels/gpu_utils.cc:49] Failed to allocate memory for convolution redzone checking; skipping this check. This is benign and only means that we won't check cudnn for out-of-bounds reads and writes. This message will only be printed once.`

Answer (score 0):

it say that you dont have enough RAM, which mean your model along with data take alot RAM on colab, try not loading all the data, and delete data from variables, list or numpy array after use using, `del` keyword.

also you can reduce batch size.